# It it possible to write C# code in backend and send results back to dart?

Tags: python, c#, firebase, flutter

Hi so I am making a website for an esport organisation. They want players to upload their Fortnite Replay file (.replay) and get stats from it.

I've found this C# library (also in python) that can read those files and extract stats:
https://github.com/Shiqan/FortniteReplayDecompressor

Since there's no dart package for doing that, I don't really know how to do that.

In other words, how to use C# as a backend for flutter? How to upload a file, do something with it in C# or python and then return extracted stats from it?

Thank you.

Comment: In the long run, you might think about perhaps an API between the two application rather than calling subprocesses. Just in case you want to separate the two processes further down the line : ) Altho it will be a bit bigger in terms of development early on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart's `Process` class allows you to execute an external command and optionally retrieve those results:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  // List all files in the current directory in UNIX-like systems.
  Process.run('ls', ['-l']).then((ProcessResult results) {
    print(results.stdout);
  });
}
```

So in your case, rather than executing `ls` like the code above, you could write a simple program in C# or Python using the library you mentioned, and have it print the results to the console in some structured format.

Then you use the Process class to run that command, read the results, then parse and display them.

See the documentation of the [Process class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process-class.html) for more details.

Comment: If I put my exe in the lib/services folder, how can i run it with Process.run?